# Creating a timetable from two lists. One of availability of interviewers and the other of preferences of interviewees

Tags: algorithm, search, graph-theory

I'm pretty sure this is a well studied problem and that there is some algorithm but I'm just not searching the right terms to find it.

I have two lists, one of a list of candiates and their preference of interviewer. Say, [{"candidate1": ["interviewer1", "interviewer9"...}...]
A second list of the interviewers' availability, say, [{"interviewer1": ["slot 1", "slot 4"].

The interviewers will have up to 30 slots but will not be available in all slots.
And the candidates should get to meet at least 1 of their top 3 preferences, and the candidates will have ranked all interviewers possible in their list of preferences. There will be more than 30 candidates, so not every candidate will meet every interviewer.

To me this is very similar to the stable marriage problem, but in that there's only one marriage for each set. In this case, each candidate will have multiple interviews. I've been trying to think about it in terms of a weighted graph and some variant of maximal pairing, but could be going down the wrong track.

I'm working in Python, but do not have any example code to share as I'm really looking for the right algorithm and would guess there are existing implementations for it once I know what it is.

Comment: I was also thinking about approaching it from a bucket sorting perspective and then ranking the preferences within each bucket, but again I think this is a 'known/solved' problem so don't want to re-invent the wheel

Comment: To me this seems very different from the stable marriage problem, in that the interviewers have no preferences. The stable marriage problem works because, given two candidates who want the same employer, we know which one to prefer, namely, whichever candidate the employer prefers. But in your problem, there's no fair way to prioritize one candidate over another.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's different to the stable marriage problem. I think there is a way to add fairness to it, since each candidate should be able to meet of their top three interviewers. Although I suspect the algorithm will not be able to guarantee a solution which is fine.

Comment: I think a possible solution, would be to break it down into n problems where n is the number of candidates. And then have a bipartite graph, matching each candidate to each interviewer based on their preference and if the interviewer has any slots left. 

And then repeat, but at each problem start from a different candidate. Perhaps alternating between the first - i and then the last - i, where i is the iteration step

Comment: One thing I don't get: is there some specific number of interviewers that each candidate will meet? Or do you create as many interviews as possible under the constraints, and it's OK if some candidates have more interviews than others? Or something else?

Comment: Ah yes apologies, no there's no constraint they should all have the same number of interviews. One could have 7 and another 11, it would be preferable that there wasn't a massive range but I'll deal with that later. The only real constraint is that each candidate should get to meet at least 1 of their top three preferences.

Comment: So, then, why not just have each candidate meet with exactly one interviewer? You can prioritize candidates based on the risk that they won't be able to meet any of their top three choices.

Comment: Ah right, no the candidates still need to meet with as many interviewers as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is an allocation problem.

First, a simplification:  Assume that there are no preferences ( or all preferences are equal ).

This is a special case of maximum flow through a graph, with multiple sources ( agents ) and sinks ( tasks ) and all edges have their capacity set to 1. If there is a 'flow' from an agent to a task, then it indicates the agent should be assigned to the task.

For a detailed discussion of this and C++ code to implement it see https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Allocate

**Variable preferences.**

I assume you want to maximize the number of high preferences that are met, because I just do not believe that your candidates are going to take the trouble to rank all 30 interviewers in any meaningful way.  To do this you could only make links between sources and sinks that are "preferred" ( perhaps the top 3 ).  This may leave some sinks ( interviewers ) under-utilized, in which case you can add links to the under-utilized sinks and recalculate the new graph.

Comment: To handle preferences, how about solving for minimum-cost maximum-flow? Where cost is a decreasing function of preference.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but the OP says this in their question post: *"And the candidates should get to meet at least 1 of their top 3 preferences, and the candidates will have ranked all interviewers possible in their list of preferences."*

Comment: "candidates will have ranked all interviewers possible"  There are 30 interviewers.  It is hard to believe that anyone would bother doing the work of ranking them all.  So, I have ignored that.  I could believe that the top 3 preferences might be selected - so add an edge to the allocation graph from each source to the top 3 preferred sinks.

Comment: They will have ranked all 30, they have to in order to complete the form.

Comment: I advise ignoring the 30 rankings.  They will be meaningless - nobody is capable of making a meaningful ranking of so many.  Whoever set this up is confused about human nature.

Comment: No, I can't just arbitrarily change or ignore requirements because you don't agree with them.